# SWT No more handles error

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am writing an Eclipse plugin(And RCP application) using SWT. In one of the views, I have 4 tabs and in couple of tabs I have many composites created with different textbox, checkbox and combobox(Tablecombo) controls. In one of the tab page, I get the org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles error. I read through multiple forum posts and see that this might be a resource leak but I am not sure how to find it in the RCP application. Also if I write a small test to create 10000 composites, I get the same SWT No more handles error.

Here is the code

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell( display );
    shell.setBounds( 10, 10, 350, 200 );
    shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() );
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )
    {
        Composite comp = new Composite( shell, SWT.NONE );
    }
    shell.open();
    while ( !shell.isDisposed() )
    {
        if ( !display.readAndDispatch() )
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: You can use [Sleak](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/tools.php) to find resource leaks.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the Sleak plugin. But How do I set tracking for the DeviceData in RCP application and where should I set it?

Comment: [This](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/04/17/finding-swt-leaks-with-sleak/) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I found this in another article too and set this one. I am able to trace and I do not find many leaks. I took snap  before i open my view and did the diff after i opened the view and see that there are only few graphics objects. Like 2 cursors, 8 Colors and 6 GCs and couple of images. Is that causing the error? Or is it because im too many composites that the RCP/SWT application cannot handle?

Comment: Hmm, that's not a lot of resources. So it has to be the sheer number of composites...

Comment: Why do you need that many composites anyway?

Comment: For ex, I have a table combo which displays 60-70 values and for each of those values that are selected, we have to provide different controls which are added in a composite. We have added all the composites with controls and then hiding them. Based on what values are selected we show the appropriate controls. Perhaps we have to look at lazy initialization and not create them upfront. But didnt think around 10000 composites would be a big deal.